# ngTable dynamic with columns doesn't show column titles

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, ngtable

In this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fVkGI1qKNtwa5Ny3tHqQ?p=preview) I have two tables, one regular `ng-table` and an `ng-table-dynamic` with columns. Both point to the same data.

The second table doesn't show column titles, how to fix that?

HTML

```
<br/> Table 1

<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="u in data" ng-dblclick="alert('double click')">
            <td title="'User ID'">{{ u.uid }}</td>
            <td title="'Group'">{{ u.ugr }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<br/> Table 2 

<table ng-table-dynamic="tableParams with cols" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
    <td title="col.nm" ng-repeat="col in cols">{{row[col.nm]}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTable']);

app.controller('myCtl', function($scope,NgTableParams) {

      $scope.cols = [ {nm:'uid'}, {nm:'ugr'} ];

      $scope.data = [ 
        { uid: 'User 1',ugr: 'Group 1'},
        { uid: 'User 2', ugr: 'Group 2'}
      ];

      $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({dataset: $scope.data});

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `title` property within your cols:

```
$scope.cols = [ {nm:'uid', title: 'User ID'}, {nm:'ugr', title: 'Group ID'} ];
```

[See this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ELXPKlgPQygUZUK0REAe).